# Access dict via dict.key

Tags: python

I created a dict `source = {'livemode': False}`. I thought it's possible to access the livemode value via `source.livemode`. But it doesn't work. Is there a way to access it that way?

As a not `source['livemode']` works, but I need `source.livemode` as that's already used in my code and I have to handle it as an alternative to the Stripe return value `charge`.

I want to give a bit more context

Here I create a charge via Stripe:

```
def _create_charge(self, request, order_reference, order_items_dict, token):
        try:
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=order_items_dict['total_gross'],
                application_fee=order_items_dict['application_fee'],
                currency=order_items_dict['event'].currency,
                source=token,
                stripe_account=order_items_dict['event'].organizer.stripe_account,
                expand=['balance_transaction', 'application_fee'],
            )

        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            body = e.json_body
            err = body.get('error', {})
            messages.error(
                request,
                err.get('message')
            )

        else:
            if charge.paid and charge.status == 'succeeded':
                return charge
```

I can access this with e.g. `charge_or_source.livemode`

```
def _create_order(self, request, charge_or_source, order_status):
        order_reference = request.session.get('order_reference')
        new_order = self.order_form.save(commit=False)
        print(charge_or_source.livemode, "charge_or_source.livemode")
        new_order_dict = {
            'total_gross': self.order_items_dict['total_gross'],
            'livemode': charge_or_source.livemode,
        }
```

Now there is a case (when the order is Free) where I have to 'skip' the `_create_charge` function but still, I have to send information about `charge_or_source.livemode`. Therefore I tried to create the above-mentioned dictionary.

Comment: There is no such thing in Python. You must be confusing it with another language.

Comment: One more thought I have is that Stripe returns a JSON object. Is it possible to access these via dict.key?

Comment: Make it a class instance then and instantiate the dict keys as attributes.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object in Python. A "JSON object" is a dictionary.

Comment: @Dschoni 's suggestion will work, but it's about as anti-python-zen as you get. And probably more work than it's worth. And why on earth is "that's already used in my code" an excuse to do things wrong?

Comment: I am a bit confused then what Stripe gives me back then. I can access charge variable via `charge.livemode`.

Comment: That's a different question.

Comment: I wrote a bit more context to hopefully explain it better what my problem is. (see edit)

Comment: Okay, I figured out now that Stripe is actually using the way @B. Morris suggested and this confused me. I now just changed it to the 'normal' way with source['livemode']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom `dict` wrapper (either a subclass of `dict` or something that contains a `dict`) and implement `__getattr__` (or `__getattribute__`) to return data from the `dict`.

```
class DictObject(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.mydict = data
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in self.mydict: return self.mydict[attr]
        return super(self, DictObject).__getattr__(attr)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a beginner myself, but let me try and answer:

Say you have a dictionary:

```
dictionary = {"One": 1, "Two": 2, "Three": 3}
```

You can create a class with its keys like:

```
class DictKeys:
    One = 'One'
    Two = 'Two'
    Three = 'Three'
```

Here, One, Two and Three are class variables or attributes, which means if you create an object for this class:

```
key = DictKeys()
```

You can access all of those keys using the '.' (dot) operator.

```
key.One
>>'One'
```

Now just plug it where ever you want to access your dictionary!

```
dictionary[key.One]
>>1
```

I'm sure this isn't the best way, and class access is a tiny bit slower than dict access, but if you really want to, you can access all your keys with a dot using this method.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Helped a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to access a dictionary is how you proposed it:

```
source['livemode']
```