# How to set python variables from JSON dictionary

Tags: python, json

Just starting out here, hopefully this is simple and someone can push me in the right direction.

1. What I have is a weather API that returns a lot of data I don't need.
2. I can pull the relevant information into a smaller json dict, this works
3. What I want to do, is set the values from the dict as variables so that everytime this runs, the variables are assigned new data

   ```
   import requests
   import json
   from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
   import datetime
   import time
   from datetime import datetime

   weatherString = requests.get('https://twcservice.mybluemix.net/api/weather/v1/geocode/33.40/-83.42/observations.json?language=en-US&units=e', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','pass'))

   data=weatherString.json()

   result = {
   "Hum": data['observation']['rh'],
   "Pressure": data['observation']['pressure'],
   "DewPt": data['observation']['dewPt'],
   "Temp": data['observation']['temp'],
   "Time": datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    }

   final = json.dumps(result)
   print(final)
   ```

In short, I would like Hum, Pressure, DewPt, Temp, and Time to be variables instead of keys in a dict if that makes sense.

Comment: Why do you need them as variables? Namespaces are great!

Comment: There is another function in the larger code that creates a JSON dict from another data source and I want to essentially append this JSON to that one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: load variables in a dict into namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597278/python-load-variables-in-a-dict-into-namespace)

Comment: Appending two JSONs definitely doesn't require you to make them local variables.

Comment: Running `globals().update(result)` will do what you want. However, it is not advisable to do this in general.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign directly to the variable, the values of which should already be typed.

```
data=weatherString.json()

data = json.loads(data)

Hum = data['observation']['rh']
Pressure = data['observation']['pressure']
DewPt = data['observation']['dewPt']
Temp = data['observation']['temp']
Time = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Thank you! But how does weatherString (the json from the API call) get passed in this case?

Comment: It's passed into `json.loads()`

Comment: That gets a "TypeError: expected string or buffer"
I'm clearly new to this, banging my head on my keyboard ha

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data as "variables" instead of "keys", you could use something like the [DictObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53514229/10619727) I proposed for a similar situation, passing in `data['observation']` (though you would need to synthesize `Time` separately and you wouldn't get the name remapping that you are implying in your question).